# MYSQL - Returning select statement when not correct?

Tags: mysql

Here's what i am trying to achieve:

Table one shows where certain products SHOULD be located on a system.
Table two shows where the products ACTUALLY are based on a live environment.

What i would like is to only return rows in Table Two IF they are in the incorrect location based on TABLE ONE.

Below is how the tables would look:

[image]

I've tried putting together my own query as below

```
SELECT product, location
FROM Table 2
WHERE product, location NOT IN
              (SELECT product, location  
               FROM Table 1)
ORDER BY LOCATION
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select * 
  from table1 
  join table2 on table1.product=table2.product 
   and table1.location <> table2.location
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!